# asp.net mvc generic/custom views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, customization

the routes are as follows

```
site.com/{section1}/{page1}
site.com/{section1}/{page2}
site.com/{section2}/{page3}
```

etc.

the pages are 2 column each where the left bar is different for each section

the page content is fetched from the database based on section + page combination

I'd like to make the page markup/layout/css be done/uploaded by the user

Questions:

- hopefully this is implemented somewhere? any links?
- how much can this be dumbed down?
- what/how can checks be enforced so that the few required tags/markup are present/visible?
- any gotchas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out using ActionAttribute